# Reading YAML file using YAMLMATLAB

Tags: matlab, yaml

I am reading YAML file in MATLAB using [YAMLMATLAB](https://code.google.com/p/yamlmatlab/). I can successfully read the file and values using the key. Here is an example.

```
yaml_file = 'Feature000000';
YamlStruct = ReadYaml(yaml_file);
features_level_1 =  YamlStruct.features1;
```

As I have many feature level so I want do the following

```
for f = 1 : 1 : nlevels
    feature_level = strcat('features', num2str(f));
    feature_level_f =  YamlStruct.feature_level;
end
```

But unfortunately, I am not able to find the mapping key. Can someone help me.

P.S: You can find Features000000 file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/95yrfwee84dgh3m/Feature000000?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I have used eval to execute the MATLAB expression. Here is the code.

```
for f = 1 : 1 : nlevels
    feature_level = strcat('features', num2str(f));
    level = strcat('layer', num2str(f));
    eval([level,'= YamlStruct.', feature_level]);
end
```